# How to use a sharedPrefs.getString into a Runnable

Tags: java, android

How I can use this sharedPrefs.getString into my Runnable ?

```
    private Runnable updateCounterThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        String tauxhoraire = sharedPrefs.getString("taux_horaire", "NULL");
        double taux=Double.parseDouble(tauxhoraire) * 100;
        int centimes = (int) (updatedTime / 1000 * (taux / 60 / 60)) ;
        int euros = centimes / 100;
        centimes = centimes % 100;
        counterVal.setText("" + euros + ","
                + String.format("%02d", centimes) + " €");
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Since when I do like that it's an error "sharedPrefs cannot be resolved" but I can't import it in the loop.

When I add it into the loop

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

I have this error "The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})"

So I tried to add it into my first loop

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String tauxhoraire = sharedPrefs.getString("taux_horaire", "NULL");
```

But resulting by the first error "sharedPrefs cannot be resolved"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Runnable object you create there is not visibilty of

**sharedPrefs**

on first path you used.

In the second path ( the one throwing *The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})"* ) the error is because of *`this`* is referred to Runnable and must be referred to a Context, for example an Activity.

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

You can try to follow your first path declaring

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs
```

member of your **Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) When I put private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefautSharedPreferences(this); in my public class MainActivity extends Activity { that's ok I don't have any error before compiling, but when I test the application it crash when loading the screen activity :/

Comment: Use this, because in onCreate the context of your Activity is not created yet SharedPreferences sharedPrefs  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()); I've updated the answer

Comment: Perfect :D I understood. Thanks for your precious help :)